# Salesforce - how to add a fixed width to a <td> cell using css?

Tags: html, css, salesforce

In Salesforce, I would like to display some fields with their respective values, however I cannot get the cell width fixed to a certain value by using CSS. What am I doing wrong ?

```
<table>
    <tr><td class="scoreInformation">Text</td><td>Value</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.THIS scoreInformation{
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: try 100% instead of 100px. It should work

Comment: what is .THIS for in front of scoreInformation? I don't assume to know everything, but .THIS seems like it is causing your css not to function. It is looking for class="THIS" and sub element of scoreInformation under it. Try just using .scoreInformation {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're missing the `.`. As it's written, the style would apply to elements with a tag name of `scoreInformation`, instead of with a class name of `scoreInformation`.

Also, the use of `.THIS` is correct, assuming that you are using this style sheet in a lightning component.

Ultimately, you're going to want to include one or both of the following:

```
/* for top level elements */
.THIS.scoreInformation{
    width: 100px;
}

/* for non-top level elements */
.THIS .scoreInformation{
    width: 100px;
}
```